# How to use the Phrase Suggester in the Elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to use the Phrase Suggester in the Elasticsearch 1.7.

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-phrase.html

So, I created below query like domcument pages sample, but I have gotten the error.

> nested: ElasticsearchIllegalArgumentException[No mapping found for
>   field [itemname]];

```
$ curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "query": {
            "query_string": {
              "fields": [
                "itemname"
              ],
              "query": "cola"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "suggest": {
    "text": "cola",
    "simple_phrase": {
      "phrase": {
        "field": "itemname",
        "size": 5,
        "real_word_error_likelihood": 0.95,
        "max_errors": 0.5,
        "gram_size": 2
      }
    }
  }
}'
```

But the ***field [itemname]]*** is definitely defined.
In fact, I can search from the itemname field with this query.

```
$ curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "query": {
            "query_string": {
              "fields": [
                "itemname"
              ],
              "query": "cola"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}'
{
  "took" : 9,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 15,
    "successful" : 15,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : 97,
    "max_score" : 11.625176,
    "hits" : [ {
      "_index" : "my_index",
      "_type" : "my_type",
      "_id" : "20615",
      "_score" : 11.625176,
      "_source":{"itemid":"20615","itemname":"cola 500ml"}
    }, {
```

In this case what's wrong with me ?
Does anyone advise me how to use the Phrase Suggester properly ?

Thanks.

Add my settings

```
# curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/my_index?pretty'
{
  "my_index" : {
    "aliases" : { },
    "mappings" : {
      "my_type" : {
        "_all" : {
          "enabled" : true,
          "analyzer" : "kuromoji_analyzer"
        },
        "properties" : {
          "itemid" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "index" : "not_analyzed",
            "store" : true
          },
          "catname" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "store" : true,
            "analyzer" : "kuromoji_analyzer"
          },
          "itemname" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "store" : true,
            "analyzer" : "kuromoji_analyzer"
          },
          "myscore" : {
            "type" : "double",
            "store" : true
          },
          "subcatname" : {
            "type" : "string",
            "store" : true,
            "analyzer" : "kuromoji_analyzer"
          }
        }
      }
    },
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have several different types defined in one of your indexes (since you're searching at the root `/`) and one doesn't have the `itemname` field?

Comment: @Val Thank you for your reply. Yes, actually as you said I have two indexes. Another index is for completion suggest. I added my setting to the  post. Are there any wrong settings ? And also I have tried adding "itemname" to the "my_index_suggest" setting and run the phrase suggest query, but I have gotten the same error.

Comment: On which index do you run your suggester? It doesn't show up in your question (i.e. first query at the top)

Comment: @Val oh,  "curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_search?pretty" is working.

Comment: Yes because `itemname` is defined in `my_type`. good then

Comment: @Val Thanks again. you are amazing :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think since you're running your suggester query on the root endpoint `/`, your search hits another index which doesn't have any mapping type defining the `itemname` field.

Try running your query directly on the index which has the mapping type that defines the `itemname` field.

According to the results of your second query, you should try running your suggester on `/my_index/my_type` instead of the root endpoint `/`

```
                        add the index and the type
                                |      |
                                v      v
curl -XPOST 'localhost:9200/my_index/my_type/_search?pretty' -d '{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "filtered": {
          "query": {
            "query_string": {
              "fields": [
                "itemname"
              ],
              "query": "cola"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "suggest": {
    "text": "cola",
    "simple_phrase": {
      "phrase": {
        "field": "itemname",
        "size": 5,
        "real_word_error_likelihood": 0.95,
        "max_errors": 0.5,
        "gram_size": 2
      }
    }
  }
}'
```